# "None" print at end of python code

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to get a python program to take a .dat file and read it into a matrix. I've it working for the most part, however "None" keeps printing at the end of the statement.

```
import sys

def main():

  matrix = generateMatrixFromFile(sys.argv[1])

  print(printMatrix(matrix))

def generateMatrixFromFile(fname):
  fp = open(fname, "r")
  row = fp.readlines()
  matrix = []
  for i in range(0, len(row), 1):
    token = row[i].split(" ")
    token[-1] = token[-1].replace('\n', '')
    matrix.append(token)
  fp.close()
  return matrix

def printMatrix(matrix):
  for i in range(0, len(matrix), 1):
    for j in range(0, len(matrix[i]), 1):
      print(matrix[i][j], sep=" ", end=" ")
    print()

main()
```

Answer (score 7):

This line:

```
print(printMatrix(matrix))
```

is printing the return value of your function, which is `None`.

Just calling `printMatrix(matrix)` should make the result as you expected.

Comment: Are you saying that in my Main function, I need to get rid of that whole print function, or just the print keyword?

Comment: In your main function, change `print(printMatrix(matrix))` to just `printMatrix(matrix)`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `print` on this line:

```
print(printMatrix(matrix))
```

Having it makes Python print the return value of `printMatrix`, which is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `printMatrix(matrix)` returns nothing (`None`) and you invoke a print on it (`print(printMatrix(matrix))`)